# How to iterate through the Array returned via async await call in react js

Tags: reactjs

Am learning reactjs and tried to load an array of users from an api via axios get call using async-await. Once i made the call,i was passing these users as a props to another component called Profiles. The profiles component simply iterates through all the users and renders a Profile component for each element of array.

I tried this without actually making the async await call by simply passing the array of users directly in the code (mock-data). It worked fine. I know am not understanding some concept of promises here.

```
const Profile = (props)=>{
  return (
    <div className='profileInfo'>
      <img src={props.avatar}/>
      <h6>{props.first_name},{props.last_name}</h6>
    </div>
  );
}
const Profiles = (props)=>{
  return (
    <div>
      {props.users.map(user=><Profile key={user.id} {...user}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
class App extends React.Component{
  getUsers = async ()=>{
    const resp = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
    return resp.data.data;
  }
  const userArray= this.getUsers();
  render(){
    return( <div>
      <Profiles users={this.userArray}/>
    </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,mountNode);
```

I am expecting to see the profiles of users rendered. But instead getting the below error:
TypeError: props.users.map is not a function
react-dom.development.js:17252 The above error occurred in the  component:
    in Profiles (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Code That Worked After setting the state:

```
const Profile = (props)=>{
  return (
    <div key={props.id} className='profileInfo'>
      <img src={props.avatar}/>
      <h5>{props.first_name}</h5>
    </div>
  );
}
class Profiles extends React.Component{
  state = {
    users:[],
  };
  getUsers = async ()=>{
    const resp = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    this.setState({users:resp.data.data});
  }
  render(){
    this.getUsers();
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(user => <Profile {...user}/>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const App=()=>{
  return (
    <div>
      <Profiles />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,mountNode);
```

Comment: `async` functions _always_ return a promise. if you log the return of `getUsers` you'll see that. you need to resolve that. you could set the user data to a state value and let React update once that has been resolved there.

Comment: Have you logged `userArray` before the `render` method? The error points that `userArray` is not actually an array. You should start by debugging that.

Comment: @Rodrigo , yes I have logged it and it's an array of users. We can directly check the API url , I provided in the code.

Comment: @rlemon, ok I will try setting user data as a state of Profiles component

Comment: This should help: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-e07daac2905f

Comment: @rlemon Setting the state has fixed the issue. Thank you